# I wouldn't be worried about... or I wouldn't worried about...?

Tags: phrase-choice

Which form is more correct?

> I wouldn't be worried about...

or

> I wouldn't worried about...

?

Comment: *Worry* as a verb emphasizes on the action (i.e. like when you keep thinking about the problem that causes you to feel worried). As a verb, someone/something can *worry* someone. *Worried* as an adjective means almost the same, but it focuses a little more on the state of unhappiness.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about the active/passive voice?

**Active:**

> Peter kicked the ball

**Passive**

> The ball was kicked by Peter

Both sentences mean the same thing, but the passive voice is used to report on events that happened so you'll find it a lot in newspapers and legal documents.

So, active voice present tense:

> I wouldn't worry about that

And the passive voice present tense:

> I wouldn't be worried about that

Active voice past tense:

> I wouldn't have worried about that

Passive past tense:

> I wouldn't have been worried about that

Active voice future tense:

> **I don't think** you'll worry about that

Passive voice future tense:

> **I don't think** you'll be worried about that

Why is the future tense different? Because when I say "I wouldn't worry about that" I'm saying "I wouldn't worry about that if **I were you**", I'm saying that **you** shouldn't need to worry, because I wouldn't worry if I were in your position.

But I can't say "I won't worry about that if I were you" because I'm combining the future tense with the past tense, which I can't do.

Comment: I do not understand this answer. It seems it does not point what variant is the correct one and if both, what's the difference in the meaning.